# Send array from Laravel and get object in Vuejs using axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

From Laravel I am sending an **array**, but on the frontend I receive an **object**, not sure why.
Maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
//BACKEND
public function index($course_id){
    $courses = CourseTopic::select([
        'course_topics.id',
        'course_topics.name',
    ])
    ->where('course_id', $course_id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->toArray();
    
    foreach ($courses as $course_topic) {
      // here I have some logic..
    }
    
    dd(gettype($courses)); -> here is Array
    return response($courses);
}


//FRONTEND
getCourseAreas(){
    this.$http.get('/course-area/' + this.course_id)
    .then(res=>{
        console.log(typeof res.data);  -> here is Object
        this.course_areas = res.data;
    })
},
```

Comment: try `response()->json($courses)`, also [typeof array is object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you use typeof on a array it returns object
2. to go safe use ->json on your response to send json formatted data to your frontend